# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to Spark Mllib and I just tried to run the sample codes from their website. However I get the Logging error. I had the same error when I tried doing some Twitter Analysis too. The error is as follows

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging**
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)`
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:616)
at scalamornprac.ML$.main(ML.scala:30)
at scalamornprac.ML.main(ML.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 21 more
16/11/10 10:02:29 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

I use **Intellij IDEA.** The sbt is as follows.

```
name := "Spark-Packt"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib-local_2.10" % "2.0.0"
```

Also note I have imported **import org.apache.log4j.{Level,Logger}** in my code. Still doesnt work.

Comment: What is spark version in platform you try to deploy your application?

Comment: I exactly didnt understand the question. The command line version of Spark I use is 1.6.1 while in Intellij I use 2.0.0. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check from spark-shell 
import org.apache.spark.Logging if it works then make proper changes in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib-local_2.10" % "1.6.1"
```

If not it means that packages of spark which you are running on environment doesn't include `org.apache.spark.Logging`